# conda how do I activate environments

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I am struggling to activate conda environments I have created on mac os x. 
Here are the environment that I have created.

```
$: conda env list
# conda environments:
#
py34                     /Students/rt12083/anaconda3/envs/py34
py35                     /Students/rt12083/anaconda3/envs/py35
root                  *  /Students/rt12083/anaconda3
```

When I try to activate them I get the following error:

```
$: source activate py34
activate: No such file or directory.
```

When i run the command `which activate` I get the following:

```
which activate
/Students/rt12083/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

my `path` variable is:

```
garnet: echo $PATH

/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:.:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/    Developer/Tools:/usr/local/GMT4.5.7/bin:/usr/local/TauP/bin:/usr/local/SU/bin:/usr/local/sac/bin:/usr/local/sac/iaspei:/usr/local/sac/macros:/Students/rt12083/anaconda3/bin
```

What do I need to do to activate the environments?

Comment: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate

Comment: I can find no reference to the error in this link?

Comment: When it says "no such file activate", means it can't find the "activate" binary in the current folder. I think you have to be in the environment's directory (or give the full path to "activate") in order to call it

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work either.

Comment: ...the activate binary is in 'Students/rt12083/anaconda3/bin' which is part of my path as you can see above. If I give the full path to "activate" it still gives the same error message.

Comment: Apparently "activate" does not work in some shells. I'll just stick the environment py34 into the path variable directly. So much for being able to create  different environments.

Comment: source /Students/rt12083/anaconda3/bin/activate py35

Answer (score 20):

Your path seems to be missing the root anaconda directory. when i echo $Path (where username is replacing my actual username) i have the following:

> /Users/username/anaconda/bin:/Users/username/anaconda/bin:/Users/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

in my bash_profile (or zshrc file etc...) I added:

> export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

I use iterm2 with zsh, although this probably applies to more general cases.

On OSX Sierra with Anaconda3 4.4.0 the path is now:

> export PATH="/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

Comment: for whatever reason, the mac at my school doesn't have the command `export`

Answer (score 3):

use the following

```
conda create -n your_Env_Name
```

Then activate it with:

```
conda activate your_Env_Name
```

Comment: This does not answer the query and hence does not fit this thread. OP is having issue with conda activate. Telling OP to run that exact command isn't going to help.

Comment: OP is asking how to activate an existing environment, not to create one and then activate!

Answer (score 0):

I use miniconda2, so not sure if this will work but: 
open terminal & navigate to wherever you have conda installed. 
for me its 
*/Users/username/miniconda 2*

and then do *source activate env_name*

and then you can navigate back to your development directory

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer is an automated way of doing that. When you execute a command, the terminal will consider as context your current working directory and the directories in your path.